# Custom theme for Browsable API not rendering properly

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to overwrite the css files for the browsable api but the theme is not rendering properly.

Specifically:

1) Navbar is not displaying properly.

2) Get Button is displaced from its correct position

3) The navigation links at the top don't have arrows or slashes.

My code

```
-proj
--app
--templates
----rest_framework
------api.html
--proj
----settings.py
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    #'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'DIRS' : [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

api.html

```
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}

{% block bootstrap_theme %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}




{% block branding %}
    <a class="navbar-brand" rel="nofollow" href="#">
        My Title
    </a>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Accordingly to the DRF documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/)

> The browsable API is built with Twitter's Bootstrap (v 3.3.5)

They point to the site Bootswatch (https://bootswatch.com/) for the ready themes, but it hosts themes for Bootstrap 4 now. It gives links like https://bootswatch.com/4/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css to download. I've just changed from 4 to 3: https://bootswatch.com/3/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css and the downloaded theme seams to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it but it doesn't worked for me even the link was correct. Actually, when we create django app sometimes its template configurations doesn't work properly. Like by default it looks inside the **template** directory but sometimes it doesn't work fine.

what you have to do is to make sure that your template directory for each app is mentioned in project settings file like in the screenshots. This hack worked for me.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1jgR.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case Browsable API not even rendering. Below changes worked for me!
change STATIC_URL in settings.py

before:  STATIC_URL = 'static/'

after:   STATIC_URL = '/static/'